# Find position of maximum per unique bin (binargmax)

Tags: python, numpy

### Setup

Suppose I have

```
bins = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
vals = np.array([8, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 5, 0, 9])
k = 3
```

I need the position of maximal values by unique bin in `bins`.

```
# Bin == 0
#  ↓ ↓           ↓
# [0 0 1 1 2 2 2 0 1 2]
# [8 7 3 4 1 2 6 5 0 9]
#  ↑ ↑           ↑
#  ⇧
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
# Maximum is 8 and happens at position 0

(vals * (bins == 0)).argmax()

0
```

---

```
# Bin == 1
#      ↓ ↓         ↓
# [0 0 1 1 2 2 2 0 1 2]
# [8 7 3 4 1 2 6 5 0 9]
#      ↑ ↑         ↑
#        ⇧
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
# Maximum is 4 and happens at position 3

(vals * (bins == 1)).argmax()

3
```

---

```
# Bin == 2
#          ↓ ↓ ↓     ↓
# [0 0 1 1 2 2 2 0 1 2]
# [8 7 3 4 1 2 6 5 0 9]
#          ↑ ↑ ↑     ↑
#                    ⇧
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
# Maximum is 9 and happens at position 9

(vals * (bins == 2)).argmax()

9
```

---

Those functions are hacky and aren't even generalizable for negative values.

### Question

How do I get all such values in the most efficient manner using Numpy?

### What I've tried.

```
def binargmax(bins, vals, k):
  out = -np.ones(k, np.int64)
  trk = np.empty(k, vals.dtype)
  trk.fill(np.nanmin(vals) - 1)

  for i in range(len(bins)):
    v = vals[i]
    b = bins[i]
    if v > trk[b]:
      trk[b] = v
      out[b] = i

  return out

binargmax(bins, vals, k)

array([0, 3, 9])
```

---

[LINK TO TESTING AND VALIDATION](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kMbEf8A0cawoQX-R74lGlaNeKBMHFfsS)

Comment: So, k is always no. of unique bins?

Comment: Yes and should be the same as `bins.max() + 1`

Comment: Are the values guaranteed to be unique per bin? Do you want all maxima?

Comment: how would you treat ties/draws? are you interested in a native python solution also?

Comment: Not guaranteed, I want the first position.  Like `np.array([1, 2, 2]).argmax()` returns `1` @user3483203

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm interested in all solutions.  However I want to know a good way to do it with Numpy.  My suspicion is that I can use some combination of `argsort` and `np.maximum.at` but couldn't figure it out.  I can use `numba` with the function I offered as my attempt and get good performance.  But what I really want is a Numpy solution using good technique.  That said, I'm still curious and would appreciate all intelligent solutions.

Comment: Sure... (-:  Sorry I missed it.  Done!

Comment: Would you mind test the speed of my solution Sir ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's one way by offsetting each group data so that we could use `argsort` on the entire data in one go -

```
def binargmax_scale_sort(bins, vals):
    w = np.bincount(bins)
    valid_mask = w!=0
    last_idx = w[valid_mask].cumsum()-1
    scaled_vals = bins*(vals.max()+1) + vals
    #unique_bins = np.flatnonzero(valid_mask) # if needed
    return len(bins) -1 -np.argsort(scaled_vals[::-1], kind='mergesort')[last_idx]
```

Comment: @piRSquared Suggestion for better solutions - Won't it better to have the unique bins being outputted for the cases where the bins don't cover the range `0-bins.max()`?

Comment: @piRSquared Yeah I am testing out with `bins, vals = gen_arrays(5000, 10000)` and my modified solution only covers for the unique ones, not the entire range and hence mismatching against `binargmax`.

Comment: I was expecting your scaled_vals as I’ve seen you use it before. Using cumsum to derive last_idx in anticipation of slicing the result of argsort!?  Brilliant!  Though I loathe the sort, I can’t deny the ingenuity.

Comment: @piRSquared Discovering I could use bincount to get the last indices per group was one of the little *eureka* moments I must admit. Interesting Q&A for sure this one. Geting argmax(first ones) needed some more brain work :)

Answer (score 19):

#### The `numpy_indexed` library:

I know this isn't technically `numpy`, but the `numpy_indexed` library has a vectorized `group_by` function which is perfect for this, just wanted to share as an alternative I use frequently:

```
>>> import numpy_indexed as npi
>>> npi.group_by(bins).argmax(vals)
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 3, 9], dtype=int64))
```

---

#### Using a simple `pandas` `groupby` and `idxmax`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bins': bins, 'vals': vals})
df.groupby('bins').vals.idxmax()
```

---

#### Using a `sparse.csr_matrix`

This option is very fast on very large inputs.

```
sparse.csr_matrix(
    (vals, bins, np.arange(vals.shape[0]+1)), (vals.shape[0], k)
).argmax(0)

# matrix([[0, 3, 9]])
```

---

#### Performance

***Functions***

```
def chris(bins, vals, k):
    return npi.group_by(bins).argmax(vals)

def chris2(df):
    return df.groupby('bins').vals.idxmax()

def chris3(bins, vals, k):
    sparse.csr_matrix((vals, bins, np.arange(vals.shape[0] + 1)), (vals.shape[0], k)).argmax(0)

def divakar(bins, vals, k):
    mx = vals.max()+1

    sidx = bins.argsort()
    sb = bins[sidx]
    sm = np.r_[sb[:-1] != sb[1:],True]

    argmax_out = np.argsort(bins*mx + vals)[sm]
    max_out = vals[argmax_out]
    return max_out, argmax_out

def divakar2(bins, vals, k):
    last_idx = np.bincount(bins).cumsum()-1
    scaled_vals = bins*(vals.max()+1) + vals
    argmax_out = np.argsort(scaled_vals)[last_idx]
    max_out = vals[argmax_out]
    return max_out, argmax_out


def user545424(bins, vals, k):
    return np.argmax(vals*(bins == np.arange(bins.max()+1)[:,np.newaxis]),axis=-1)

def user2699(bins, vals, k):
    res = []
    for v in np.unique(bins):
        idx = (bins==v)
        r = np.where(idx)[0][np.argmax(vals[idx])]
        res.append(r)
    return np.array(res)

def sacul(bins, vals, k):
    return np.lexsort((vals, bins))[np.append(np.diff(np.sort(bins)), 1).astype(bool)]

@njit
def piRSquared(bins, vals, k):
    out = -np.ones(k, np.int64)
    trk = np.empty(k, vals.dtype)
    trk.fill(np.nanmin(vals))

    for i in range(len(bins)):
        v = vals[i]
        b = bins[i]
        if v > trk[b]:
            trk[b] = v
            out[b] = i

    return out
```

***Setup***

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from timeit import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numba import njit
from scipy import sparse

res = pd.DataFrame(
       index=['chris', 'chris2', 'chris3', 'divakar', 'divakar2', 'user545424', 'user2699', 'sacul', 'piRSquared'],
       columns=[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000],
       dtype=float
)

k = 5

for f in res.index:
    for c in res.columns:
        bins = np.random.randint(0, k, c)
        k = 5
        vals = np.random.rand(c)
        df = pd.DataFrame({'bins': bins, 'vals': vals})
        stmt = '{}(df)'.format(f) if f in {'chris2'} else '{}(bins, vals, k)'.format(f)
        setp = 'from __main__ import bins, vals, k, df, {}'.format(f)
        res.at[f, c] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=50)

ax = res.div(res.min()).T.plot(loglog=True)
ax.set_xlabel("N");
ax.set_ylabel("time (relative)");

plt.show()
```

***Results***

[image]

***Results with a much larger `k`*** (This is where broadcasting gets hit hard):

```
res = pd.DataFrame(
       index=['chris', 'chris2', 'chris3', 'divakar', 'divakar2', 'user545424', 'user2699', 'sacul', 'piRSquared'],
       columns=[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000],
       dtype=float
)

k = 500

for f in res.index:
    for c in res.columns:
        bins = np.random.randint(0, k, c)
        vals = np.random.rand(c)
        df = pd.DataFrame({'bins': bins, 'vals': vals})
        stmt = '{}(df)'.format(f) if f in {'chris2'} else '{}(bins, vals, k)'.format(f)
        setp = 'from __main__ import bins, vals, df, k, {}'.format(f)
        res.at[f, c] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=50)

ax = res.div(res.min()).T.plot(loglog=True)
ax.set_xlabel("N");
ax.set_ylabel("time (relative)");

plt.show()
```

[image]

As is apparent from the graphs, broadcasting is a nifty trick when the number of groups is small, however the time complexity/memory of broadcasting increases too fast at higher `k` values to make it highly performant.

Comment: Mind adding the timing of mine?

Comment: Nice benchmark! As the author of numpy_indexed, let me note that the library is optimized to be 'numpythonic' and generic. That is, your bins need not be ints starting at 0; but could be any type, and any dimension ndarray infact. That does add a little overhead here and there, but if performance is your primary goal then indeed there is no arguing with numba for this type of problem. Still good to have a reference implementation with a simple API to test your low level code against though!

Comment: Very nice use of sparse. You’ve given me two good ideas for my tool box.

Comment: You might want to test using a CSR vs. a CSC sparse matrix here. Because of the type of operating being done, one might be faster. I think the arguments are just about the same. I’ll post the CSC solution when I’m at a computer.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, here's my linear-time entry, using only indexing and `np.(max|min)inum.at`.  It assumes bins go up from 0 to max(bins).

```
def via_at(bins, vals):
    max_vals = np.full(bins.max()+1, -np.inf)
    np.maximum.at(max_vals, bins, vals)
    expanded = max_vals[bins]
    max_idx = np.full_like(max_vals, np.inf)
    np.minimum.at(max_idx, bins, np.where(vals == expanded, np.arange(len(bins)), np.inf))
    return max_vals, max_idx
```

Answer (score 9):

How about this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bins = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
>>> vals = np.array([8, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 5, 0, 9])
>>> k = 3
>>> np.argmax(vals*(bins == np.arange(k)[:,np.newaxis]),axis=-1)
array([0, 3, 9])
```

Comment: That is clever (-:  The time complexity and memory demand will blow up with large k (I think).

Comment: @piRSquared, I've put in some benchmarks for that.  With 30 or so bins it works great, with 1000 performance drops.  With only 3 bins it's by far the fastest answer.

Comment: I'm doing the same.  This should be linear by length of `vals`.  My initial approach is the fastest when I apply Numba's `njit`.  I'll show it.  I wanted an O(n) Numpy approach.  This does come close.

Answer (score 8):

If you're going for readability, this might not be the best solution, but I think it works

```
def binargsort(bins,vals):
    s = np.lexsort((vals,bins))
    s2 = np.sort(bins)
    msk = np.roll(s2,-1) != s2
    # or use this for msk, but not noticeably better for performance:
    # msk = np.append(np.diff(np.sort(bins)),1).astype(bool)
    return s[msk]

array([0, 3, 9])
```

**Explanation**:

`lexsort` sorts the indices of `vals` according to the sorted order of `bins`, then by the order of `vals`:

```
>>> np.lexsort((vals,bins))
array([7, 1, 0, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9])
```

So then you can mask that by where sorted `bins` differ from one index to the next:

```
>>> np.sort(bins)
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])

# Find where sorted bins end, use that as your mask on the `lexsort`
>>> np.append(np.diff(np.sort(bins)),1)
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])

>>> np.lexsort((vals,bins))[np.append(np.diff(np.sort(bins)),1).astype(bool)]
array([0, 3, 9])
```

Comment: See the validation section of my link in question.  This is returning the last position of the max.

Comment: hmm... my edited solution (using `s2 = np.sort(bins); msk = np.roll(s2,-1) != s2`) passes the first 2 validations but not the third... not sure what's going on, trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 7):

This is a fun little problem to solve.  My approach is to to get an index into `vals` based on the values in `bins`.  Using `where` to get the points where the index is `True` in combination with `argmax` on those points in vals gives the resulting value.

```
def binargmaxA(bins, vals):
    res = []
    for v in unique(bins):
        idx = (bins==v)
        r = where(idx)[0][argmax(vals[idx])]
        res.append(r)
    return array(res)
```

It's possible to remove the call to `unique` by using `range(k)` to get possible bin values.  This speeds things up, but still leaves it with poor performance as the size of k increases.

```
def binargmaxA2(bins, vals, k):
    res = []
    for v in range(k):
        idx = (bins==v)
        r = where(idx)[0][argmax(vals[idx])]
        res.append(r)
    return array(res)
```

Last try, comparing each value slows things down substantially.  This version computes the sorted array of values, rather than making a comparison for each unique value. Well, it actually computes the sorted indices and only gets the sorted values when needed, as that avoids one time loading vals into memory. Performance still scales with the number of bins, but much slower than before.

```
def binargmaxB(bins, vals):
    idx = argsort(bins)   # Find sorted indices
    split = r_[0, where(diff(bins[idx]))[0]+1, len(bins)]  # Compute where values start in sorted array
    newmax = [argmax(vals[idx[i1:i2]]) for i1, i2 in zip(split, split[1:])]  # Find max for each value in sorted array
    return idx[newmax +split[:-1]] # Convert to indices in unsorted array
```

### Benchmarks

Here's some benchmarks with the other answers.

#### 3000 elements

With a somewhat larger dataset (`bins = randint(0, 30, 3000);  vals = randn(3000)`; k=30;)

- **171us** binargmax_scale_sort2 by Divakar
- **209us** this answer, version B
- **281us** binargmax_scale_sort by Divakar
- **329us** broadcast version by user545424
- **399us** this answer, version A
- **416us** answer by sacul, using lexsort
- **899us** reference code by piRsquared

#### 30000 elements

And an even larger dataset (`bins = randint(0, 30, 30000);   vals = randn(30000)`; k=30).  Surprisingly this doesn't change the relative performance between solutions.

- **1.27ms** this answer, version B
- **2.01ms** binargmax_scale_sort2 by Divakar
- **2.38ms** broadcast version by user545424
- **2.68ms** this answer, version A
- **5.71ms** answer by sacul, using lexsort
- **9.12ms** reference code by piRSquared

**Edit** I didn't change `k` with the increasing number of possible bin values, now that I've fixed that the benchmarks are more even.

#### 1000 bin values

Increasing the number unique bin values may also have an impact on performance.  The solutions by Divakar and sacul are mostly unaffected, while the others have quite a substantial impact.
`bins = randint(0, 1000, 30000);  vals = randn(30000); k = 1000`

- **1.99ms** binargmax_scale_sort2 by Divakar
- **3.48ms** this answer, version B
- **6.15ms** answer by sacul, using lexsort
- **10.6ms** reference code by piRsquared
- **27.2ms** this answer, version A
- **129ms** broadcast version by user545424

**Edit** Including benchmarks for the reference code in the question, it's surprisingly competitive especially with more bins.

Answer (score 3):

I know you said to use Numpy, but if Pandas is acceptable:

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd;
(pd.DataFrame(
    {'bins':np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]),
     'values':np.array([8, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 5, 0, 9])}) 
.groupby('bins')
.idxmax())

      values
bins        
0          0
1          3
2          9
```