# Calculating length of sequence of zeros in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this

| Unit | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | 1 |
| One | 1 | 2 |
| One | 1 | 3 |
| One | 0 | 4 |
| One | 0 | 5 |
| One | 1 | 6 |
| One | 1 | 7 |

and I want to create a new column where I'd have the size of the sequence of zeros from the `status` column. So for that example, the output would be

| Unit | status | date | gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| One | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| One | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| One | 0 | 4 | 2 |
| One | 0 | 5 | 2 |
| One | 1 | 6 | 0 |
| One | 1 | 7 | 0 |

This would have to be done for all the units in the DataFrame. I was basing myself on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60734125/count-the-number-of-zeros-between-two-non-zero-numbers-sequentially-in-a-datafra), but I'm stuck in the part where I set the total size for all the rows that are part of the gap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to group the block of some values is to `cumsum` on the other values. Given that your data is sorted by `Unit`:

```
df['gap'] = (df.groupby(['Unit', 'status', df['status'].cumsum()])
             ['status'].transform('size')
             .where(df['status'].eq(0), other=0)
            )
```

Output:

```
  Unit  status  date  gap
0  One       1     1    0
1  One       1     2    0
2  One       1     3    0
3  One       0     4    2
4  One       0     5    2
5  One       1     6    0
6  One       1     7    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, yeah it makes a lot of sense to use cumsum to group the block.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use run-length encoding via package [`python-rle`](https://pypi.org/project/python-rle/):

```
import rle 

r = rle.encode(df.status)

df['gap'] = (rle
  .decode([r[1][x] if r[0][x] == 0 else 0 for x in range(len(r[0]))], r[1]))
```

Output:

```
 Unit  status  date  gap
0  One       1     1    0
1  One       1     2    0
2  One       1     3    0
3  One       0     4    2
4  One       0     5    2
5  One       1     6    0
6  One       1     7    0
```