# Count consecutive rows above limit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of a name and speed measurements for each 0.1 seconds.
I want to get a count of how many times the speed is above the speed limit for 0.3 seconds (i.e. 3 consecutive rows).

```py
limit = 25.3

Name   speed   time
Mary   25.6    0.1
Mary   25.8    0.2
Mary   25.1    0.3
Mary   24.4    0.4
Mary   24.2    0.5
Mary   25.8    0.6
Mary   25.9    0.7
Mary   25.8    0.8
Mary   25.4    0.9
Mary   24.9    1.0
Mary   25.6    1.1
Mary   25.8    1.2
Mary   26.2    1.3
```

Result

```py
{Mary: 2}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is create groups by consecutive values and aggregate counts per grsoups and `Name`, filter if greater or equal like `limit` and again counts by `Name`s:

```
limit = 25.3

m = df['speed'].gt(limit)
s = df.groupby([(~m).shift().bfill()[m].cumsum(),'Name']).size()
s = s[s.ge(3)].groupby(level=1).size()
print (s)
Mary    2
dtype: int64
```

Or create counter of consecutive values, filter for equal by `3` and count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
limit = 25.3

m = df['speed'].gt(limit)

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/52718619/2901002
b = m.cumsum()
c = b.sub(b.mask(m).ffill().fillna(0)).astype(int)

df['count'] = c
print (df)

s = df.loc[df['count'].eq(3), 'Name'].value_counts()
print (s)
Mary    2
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```