# How to make flag column value 1 when 5 consective rows in other column are 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have one datafrmae which includes two columns flag and flag1, i want to check if flag column values greater than 1 for 5 times or greater than 5 times continuous flag1 value should change to 1

```
here is example

df=pd.DataFrame({'flag':[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],'flag1':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

Comment: What happens if there is a string of 20 '1' ?  Woud it be a) 00001000000000000000 or b) 00001000010000100001 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create consecutive counts and then test `5` if equal:

```
a = df['flag'].eq(1)
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/52718619/2901002
b = a.cumsum()
df['new'] = b.sub(b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0)).eq(5).astype(int)


print (df)
    flag  flag1  new
0      0      0    0
1      0      0    0
2      1      0    0
3      1      0    0
4      1      0    0
5      1      0    0
6      1      1    1
7      1      0    0
8      1      0    0
9      0      0    0
10     0      0    0
11     0      0    0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (b.sub(b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0)))
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     1.0
3     2.0
4     3.0
5     4.0
6     5.0
7     6.0
8     7.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
11    0.0
Name: flag, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

setup

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'flag':[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],'flag1':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

solution

```
rolling_sum = df["flag"].rolling(5).sum()
df["check"] = ((rolling_sum == 5) & (rolling_sum.diff() == 1)).astype(int)

    flag  flag1  check
0      0      0      0
1      0      0      0
2      1      0      0
3      1      0      0
4      1      0      0
5      1      0      0
6      1      1      1
7      1      0      0
8      1      0      0
9      0      0      0
10     0      0      0
11     0      0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

2 versions of the solution, slow and fast for a len(df) = 3300000

Slow:

```
%%time
d = 1
for i,v in df.iterrows():
    if (v.flag == 1) and (d<5) :
        df.at[i,'flag1'] = 0
        d+=1
    elif (v.flag == 1):
        df.at[i,'flag1'] = 1
        d=1
    else:
        df.at[i,'flag1'] = 0
        d=1
df['flag2']=df['flag1'].astype(int)

Wall time: 4min 27s
```

Fast:

```
%%time
from math import floor
d = 1
df['flag1'] = (
        [(0,(d:=1))[0] if df.at[i,'flag']==0 
    else (0, (d := d+1))[0] if (d%5)!=0
    else (1, (d :=1 ))[0]
    for i in range(len(df))
    ] )

Wall time: 1min 1s
```

Ignore the "new" column.

|  | flag | flag1 | flag2 | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 14 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 15 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 16 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 18 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 21 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 22 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 23 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 24 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 26 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 27 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 28 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 29 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 30 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 31 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 32 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 33 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 34 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 35 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 36 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 37 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 39 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 40 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 41 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 42 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 43 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 44 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 45 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 46 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 47 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 48 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 49 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

For testing purpose, this is how I generated the data:

```
A = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]
A = A * 100000
df=pd.DataFrame({'flag':A})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316

Comment: @jezrael Thanks very much for the link.  It is very useful for me.  I tried different algorithms or pandas manipulation. And I also tried your method.  But I found that the output are different. eg Index=21 when there is a long line of 1s.  I've written to clarify with OP on the requirements on this.  But for academic purpose, the different I find is the need to keep track of the "state change".  I couldn't find a way to "remember" the last change when I use pandas manipulation.  Once again, thanks very much.