# Python Pandas DataFrame: Add a counter based on condition for 2 cases

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, counter

I want to produce two counters ("**counter1**", "**counter2**") in the following dataframe examples (cases: 1 and 2) using python functions with these characteristics:

**case 1:**

1. "**counter1**": it counts the number of the **zeros** in the column "case1-0". (cumulative sum of the zeros)
2. "**counter2**": it counts the **ones** in the column "case1-0". However, "**counter2**" is reseted, starting counting from 1 if "**counter1**" has the values 3. As shown in the example, "**counter2**" keeps counting as long as "**counter1**" less than 3 --> the zeros in column "case1-0" are considered as ones if "**counter1**" < 3.

| case1-0 | counter1 | counter2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 2 | 5 |
| 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 0 | 6 |

**case 2:**

1. "**counter1**": it counts the number of the **ones** in the column "case1-0". (cumulative sum of the ones)
2. "**counter2**": it counts the number of the **zeros** in the column "case1-0" but only if the last previous value in "**counter1**" is greater than 3.

| case1-0 | counter1 | counter2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | **4** | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | **1** |
| 0 | 0 | **2** |
| 0 | 0 | **3** |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

In the reality I have a time serie. Therefore the approach should be applicable for greater data frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For count consecutive `0` values is possible use [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52718619/2901002) with create mask by compare by `0`. Alterntive is more complicated and slowier, if larger data. It create consecutive groups by compare shifted values and count by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) similar like last column `counter22` with groups created by cumulative sum if greater or equal `3` by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
a = df['case1-0'].eq(0)
b = a.cumsum()
df['counter11'] = b.sub(b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0)).astype(int)
#alternative
#s = df['case1-0'].ne(df['case1-0'].shift()).cumsum()
#df['counter11'] = df.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).mask(df['case1-0'].ne(0),0)

df['counter22'] = df.groupby(df['counter11'].ge(3).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
print (df)
    case1-0  counter1  counter2  counter11  counter22
0         1         0         1          0          1
1         1         0         2          0          2
2         1         0         3          0          3
3         0         1         4          1          4
4         0         2         5          2          5
5         0         3         1          3          1
6         1         0         2          0          2
7         1         0         3          0          3
8         0         1         4          1          4
9         0         2         5          2          5
10        1         0         6          0          6
```

Comment: thank you so much I appreciate it. I would be very thankful If you help me solving the similar problem described in case 2 above. I just added it now. I want to have a counter2 starting counting the zeros in column "case1-0" only if the last previous value of counter1 is greater than 3.