# Python Pandas Dataframe: conditional counters of one and zeros values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, counter

I want to add two columns in my dataframe with the following function using python:

1. "**counter1**": it counts the number of the **ones** in the column "case1-0". (cumulative sum of the ones)
2. "**counter2**": it counts the number of the **zeros** in the column "case1-0" but only if the last previous value in "**counter1**" is greater than 3.

| case1-0 | counter1 | counter2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | **4** | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | **1** |
| 0 | 0 | **2** |
| 0 | 0 | **3** |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

In the reality I have a time serie. Therefore the approach should be applicable for greater data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52718619/2901002) with `a` mask for compare by `1` for `counter11` and for `counter22` is replaced not `1` values of column `counter11` to missing values and forward filling them, so possible compare for greater values like `3` and pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) values of `s` helper `Series`:

```
a = df['case1-0'].eq(1)
b = a.cumsum()
df['counter11'] = b.sub(b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0)).astype(int)

a1 = ~a
b = a1.cumsum()
s = b.sub(b.mask(a1).ffill().fillna(0)).astype(int)

df['counter22'] = np.where(df['counter11'].where(a).ffill().gt(3) & a1, s, 0)
print (df)
    case1-0  counter1  counter2  counter11  counter22
0         1         1         0          1          0
1         1         2         0          2          0
2         1         3         0          3          0
3         1         4         0          4          0
4         0         0         1          0          1
5         0         0         2          0          2
6         0         0         3          0          3
7         1         1         0          1          0
8         1         2         0          2          0
9         0         0         0          0          0
10        0         0         0          0          0
11        1         1         0          1          0
```

Explanation how it working:

```
print (df.assign(counter0 = s,
                 replaced=df['counter11'].where(a),
                 ffill= df['counter11'].where(a).ffill(),
                 mask = df['counter11'].where(a).ffill().gt(3),
                 chained = df['counter11'].where(a).ffill().gt(3) & a1,
                 counter22 = np.where(df['counter11'].where(a).ffill().gt(3) & a1, s, 0)))
```

---

```
    case1-0  counter1  counter2  counter11  counter0  replaced  ffill   mask  \
0         1         1         0          1         0       1.0    1.0  False   
1         1         2         0          2         0       2.0    2.0  False   
2         1         3         0          3         0       3.0    3.0  False   
3         1         4         0          4         0       4.0    4.0   True   
4         0         0         1          0         1       NaN    4.0   True   
5         0         0         2          0         2       NaN    4.0   True   
6         0         0         3          0         3       NaN    4.0   True   
7         1         1         0          1         0       1.0    1.0  False   
8         1         2         0          2         0       2.0    2.0  False   
9         0         0         0          0         1       NaN    2.0  False   
10        0         0         0          0         2       NaN    2.0  False   
11        1         1         0          1         0       1.0    1.0  False   

    chained  counter22  
0     False          0  
1     False          0  
2     False          0  
3     False          0  
4      True          1  
5      True          2  
6      True          3  
7     False          0  
8     False          0  
9     False          0  
10    False          0  
11    False          0
```

**Alternative solution**

`counter` is for count consecutive `0` and `1` values by compare shifted values for groups with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then for `counter11` set 0 if not match condition `mask` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and for `counter22` is used same solution like above (only changed variables):

```
mask = df['case1-0'].eq(1)
counter = df.groupby(df['case1-0'].ne(df['case1-0'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
df['counter11'] = counter.where(mask, 0)
df['counter22'] = np.where(df['counter11'].where(mask).ffill().gt(3) & ~mask, counter, 0)

print (df)
    case1-0  counter1  counter2  counter11  counter22
0         1         1         0          1          0
1         1         2         0          2          0
2         1         3         0          3          0
3         1         4         0          4          0
4         0         0         1          0          1
5         0         0         2          0          2
6         0         0         3          0          3
7         1         1         0          1          0
8         1         2         0          2          0
9         0         0         0          0          0
10        0         0         0          0          0
11        1         1         0          1          0
```

Comment: great thanks! I would be more thankful if you would explain some of the steps for counter22

Comment: @jess - Can you check edited answer? Added steps in helper DataFrame for see how it working.

Comment: awsome I appreciate! it is definitely more clear! just other two questions: can you explain the role of the tilde symbol- the bitwise operator- in this case and the functionality and utility of the groubby.cumcount - unfortunately I did not find clear examples in the internet when it is applied.

Comment: @jess - added to answer. `~mask` is same like `mask == False`, it inverse `True` with `False`, So [True, False, True] is [False, True, False]